# SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot attach file

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC application that connects to a local mdf database file in the same folder using this in `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ImportNUS" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFileName=C:\Users\Chase\Desktop\DDAC Assignment\DDAC Assignment - CMS\CMS Databases\N.US.mdf;Initial Catalog=NUS, Integrated Security=true;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and this:

```
@{
var DB = Database.Open("ImportNUS");

var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM IMPORT ORDER by Customer ID";}

   <div id="Import" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Import</h3>

            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Description</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

                    @foreach(var row in DB.Query(selectQueryString)){ 
                    <tr>
                        <td>@row.Container ID</td>
                        <td>@row.Warehouse ID</td>
                        <td>@row.Imported From</td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                  }
                }
            </table>
        </div>
```

I get this error:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot attach file 'C:\Users\Chase\Desktop\DDAC Assignment\DDAC Assignment - CMS\CMS Databases\N.US.mdf' as database 'NUS, Integrated Security=true' because this file is already in use for database 'N.US,Container ID=containerid,Warehouse ID=WarehouseID,Imported From=IF']

This has being troubling me for the past couple of days. Sorry I am new to this, but could you please give me some advise on how to solve this? I would really appreciate it. I just want to connect to the `.mdf` database file.

Comment: clarify which line of code throws the exception

Comment: Line 61: @foreach(var row in DB.Query(selectQueryString)){

Answer (score 0):

Using **WebMatrix**, You may take a look at the [tutorials](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/5-working-with-data) available on the asp.net site.